# how do i update a one to many map table?

Tags: mysql

the first is the sectors table that has an id and sector name like this

```
id   |    sector
1    |    Government
2    |    Education
```

The second is the employee table like this (simplified)

```
Id    |    name
1     |    sam
2     |    tom
```

Finally I have a sectorMap table (this is used to join the two tables above together) like this

```
Id    |     sectorid    |    employeeid
1     |     1               |    2
2     |     1               |    1
3     |     2               |    2
```

So in this instance, once I join everything together and view the sectors or each employee, it would show that tom has two sectors (government, education) and sam only has one (government)… hope that makes sense

My question is, within my application, the user has the ability to change these sectors by selecting from a multiple selection dropdown in html. For some reason I thought that by doing an update on duplicate expression would work, however seeing how I have multiple rows of data, I would need to delete all rows within the sectormap table that do not reflect the new selection and contain the selected employees id. What would be the best way of going about that?

For instance, in this case, lets say I open the application and see that tom has two sectors tied to him (government, education) and I only wanted him to have one (government). When I deselect education and select GO. The application returns a list to the server that contains (‘government’). How can I formulate an expression to delete the education sector row from the sectormap table that contains his id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is in your question.

1st when you are deselecting education. You will get data of (‘government’). right?
So just invert your query. select those records **which is not (‘government’)**, those are **education**.
So, **education** records are you can delete.
Hope this will help you. thanks:)

Comment: not sure why i didnt notice that...
this works great. 
```
DELETE sectors_map FROM sectors_map
LEFT JOIN employees on employees.id = sectors_map.employee_id
LEFT JOIN sectors on sectors.id = sectors_map.sector_id
WHERE CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE 'John Smith'
AND sector NOT IN ('Government', 'Education');`
```

Comment: @wmunsell Thanks :). don't forgot to up-vote answer if it is helpful to you.